# Google App Script delete rows not working while sheet is protected

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am having a google apps script to clear the googlesheet empty rows, it was working previously but recently encountered issue as mentioned.

error message

> Exception: Service Spreadsheets failed while accessing document with id XXXX.

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please add a [mcve] and add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask]. P.S. Searching the error message and the google apps script tag returns 16 results --> see [search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bgoogle-apps-script%5d%20Exception%3a%20Service%20Spreadsheets%20failed%20while%20accessing%20document%20with%20id&searchOn=3)

Answer (score 0):

Deletes all empty rows:

```
function delMTs() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
  const vs = sh.getDataRange().getValues();
  let d = 0;
  vs.forEach((r,i)=>{
    if(r.join()=='') {
      sh.deleteRow(i+1-d++);
    }
  });
}
```